# MySQL: outer alias in subquery: diff between WHERE and ON

Tags: mysql, sql

Despite there are many similar questions, I didn't find the answer.

**My query:**

```
SELECT bg2.id FROM big_table bg1
JOIN middle_table md ON  bg1.url_id = md.id1
JOIN big_table bg2  ON bg2.url_id = md.id2
AND [a lot of conditions]
AND bg2.dependency_to_other_table NOT IN (
    SELECT DISTINCT ot.id FROM big_table bg
    JOIN other_table ot ON bg.dependency = ot.id
    -- AND bg.value = bg1.value DOESN'T WORK
    WHERE bg.value = bg1.value -- WORKS CORRECT
);
```

**Question:** *why I can't use outer alias in `ON` clause, but can in `WHERE` clause?*

Comment: is your second JOIN clause even correct? could you share the whole query?

Comment: @Ashalynd its too big. I don't change query, but only change the `AND id = t1.id` to `WHERE id = t2.id` string. Everything else is untouched.

Comment: well, at least say which tables you are trying to join in the second case, otherwise the JOIN clause looks malformed. Also, in your AND clause you refer to `t1.id`, in the WHERE clause you refer to `t2.id`. Is `t1.id` part of your `t1` selection?

Comment: @Ashalynd updated query. That fact that `AND` and `WHERE` pointed to different tables was just a typo

Comment: Ah, that's easy. I suspect it's because all relations mentioned in JOIN clause should be related to the joined tables. But you are joining `bg` and `ot` while conditioning on `bg1`.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you just can't join different tables in one join statement.

**bg**.dependency = **ot**.id vs **bg**.value = **bg1**.value